# "I went to bed hungry" vs. "I went to bed hungrily"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, american-english, adverbs

What is the exact difference between "I went to bed hungry" and "I went to bed hungrily"?

Comment: Better on ELL. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2

Comment: This is talking about being hungry for food, not for sex or something else, right?

Comment: Patsy Cline sang a song back in the 1960s: _Hungry for Love_: 'I'm hungry for love // Like a hobo for food // Like the devil hunts for bad  // Like the angel looks for good /// I've been oh, so lonesome // Your letters aren't enough // My arms will welcome you home, dear // I'm hungry for love".  The singer went to bed _hungrily_.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Journey Park. Please tell us what you found when you looked in the dictionary (you *did* look in the dictionary, didn't you?), and describe exactly why you're still puzzled. (It's OK to be more confused after reading the dictionary than you were before; happens to me all the time. But you have to "show your work"; otherwise, we have no way of knowing what you already know and where your confusion lies.)

Answer (score 4):

A speaker who goes to bed hungry hasn’t had enough to eat. A speaker who goes to bed hungrily hasn’t had enough sex.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main difference is that "I went to bed hungry" is common English usage.  "I went to bed hungrily" is not.

In terms of meaning?  I would say that the former means that you were hungry when you went to bed; maybe you didn't eat dinner.  The latter implies that there was something unusual about the manner in which you went to bed.

Comment: Not too unusual I hope, everyone should go to bed hungrily at least a few times in their lives. Hopefully with someone who is just as hungry for what will follow.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective **hungry** in *I went to bed hungry* attributes a quality to the pronoun **I**, giving more information about "**me**":

> I, being hungry, went to bed.

The adverb **hungrily** in *I went to bed hungrily* attributes a quality to the verb **went**, just like *[That escalated quickly](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FONN-0uoTHI)*, giving more information about how "**I**" went to bed. So it would imply that

> I went to bed in a rather hungry fashion (probably because there was a sexually attractive woman or man on the bed and I was going to do something to pleasure myself or because there was a loaf of bread on the bed and I was going to eat it, etc).